# Case When value is x OR y, then z

Tags: sql, netsuite

need to return transaction # if field is either X OR Y.
I have it working if the field option is only X but do not know how to add "OR" into the formula

Tried the Numeric formula that works if value is X but did not work with two options

Case when {custbody_opp_opptype} = 'New Buying Group/Existing Solution' or 'New Buying Group/New Solution' then {transactionnumber} else null end

would like to display transaction # if the Opp Type field= either of the choices noted above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're not comparing the second condition to anything. It looks like it should be;

```
CASE WHEN 
{custbody_opp_opptype} = 'New Buying Group/Existing Solution' OR
{custbody_opp_opptype} = 'New Buying Group/New Solution' 
THEN {transactionnumber} ELSE NULL END
```